# 7zip current date with source folder on other path dir

Tags: batch-file, 7zip

I am trying to zip files with only lastest file modified using 7z, I've take a look at this 
https://superuser.com/questions/206817/7-zip-cmd-add-current-date-to-archive-and-include-only-the-last-modified-folder

and this

[Use 7zip to include files with *current date* only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335743/use-7zip-to-include-files-with-current-date-only)

but they are not in different dir which I have trouble with, currently my command code is like this

```
@ECHO ON

SET SourceDir=H:\spiral\kmart\inbox
SET DestDir= C:\TCD


CD \TCD
7z.exe a -tzip C:\TCD\KMartInboxXML.zip-i!^C:\TCD\%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%-%DATE:~10,4%.xml "H:\spiral\kmart\inbox\*"


SET DestDir= C:\TCD
pause

EXIT
```

and I got this error(see pict)

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rerJ8.png)

I know I used wrong dir because wrong command and actually I have tried different command line using forfiles also, I am lost. Any help is very appreciated.

EDIT:

Missing explanation.

Comment: This does not appear to be a batch file issue despite the fact I would change every single line of code you have posted. but more a how do I use the 7z command line. What are you trying to use the **`-i`** switch for? and why not put a space just before it?

Comment: @Compo Hi, thanks for responding, sorry I was complete noob to batch file.. I was trying to following the command line like on the link xD . I have figure it out by myself though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have found a fix for your 7z.exe command, change the rest of the script to:

```bat
@ECHO OFF

SET "SourceDir=H:\spiral\kmart\inbox"
SET "ZipName=files_kmartinbox.zip"
SET "DestDir=C:\TCD"
SET "now=%date:~12,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%"

CD /D "%DestDir%"
7z.exe a "%ZipName%" -r "%SourceDir%\*%now%*"
```

Also note that if 7z.exe isn't in %PATH% or %DestDir% you would have to provide it's full or relative path too.

Answer (score 1):

Got help from my friend, figure it out by altering zip command on the source folder.
Because the file is using date,
I use variable to find them... format name file is 290427-SHIPMENT-1704180803.xml

So I describe the variable as this

```
SET now=%date:~12,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%
```

will result:

```
170418
```

so, any file with file name 170418(that is today) will get zipped, place them in the variable in zip source folder.

Here is the complete code

```
@ECHO ON


SET SourceDir=H:\spiral\kmart\inbox
SET DestDir= C:\TCD
SET now=%date:~12,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%


C:
CD \TCD
7z.exe a files_kmartinbox.zip -r "H:\spiral\kmart\inbox\*%now%*" 


SET DestDir= C:\TCD
```

I hope this is helping people with similliar same problem. Cheers.