# How to copy a file with an incremented version number in file name depending on existing files?

Tags: batch-file

I have the batch file below:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\53bba593f5d69be\public\uploads\*.xlsx" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I

FOR /F "delims=" %%a IN ('wmic OS Get localdatetime ^| find "."') DO SET DateTime=%%a

set Yr=%DateTime:~0,4%
set Mon=%DateTime:~4,2%
set Day=%DateTime:~6,2%

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "baseName=InventoryReport%Yr%-%Mon%-%Day% V1.%n%"
set "n=0"
FOR /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'DIR /b /ad "%baseName%*"^|findstr /xri "\\192.168.0.141\Medisun\28 - Business Development\30 - Product Inventory\InventoryReport\"%baseName%[0-9]*""'
) do (
  set "name=%%F"
  set "name=!name:*%baseName%=!"
  if !name! gtr !n! set "n=!name!"
)
set /a n+=1
md "%baseName%%n%"


copy "%C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\53bba593f5d69be\public\uploads\%NewestFile%" "\\192.168.0.141\Medisun\28 - Business Development\30 - Product Inventory\InventoryReport\%baseName%%n%.xlsx"
cmd /k
```

I cannot get it to find the greatest version number of previously copied file between `V1.` and file extension `.xlsx` in file name and increment it but one. The batch file finds the file `V1.1`, but overwrites it instead of copying newest file with `V1.2` in target file name.

How can I get the previous file version first and increment that number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file copying task can be done with following batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "SourceFolder=C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\53bba593f5d69be\public\uploads"
set "TargetFolder=\\192.168.0.141\Medisun\28 - Business Development\30 - Product Inventory\InventoryReport"

for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir "%SourceFolder%\*.xlsx" /A-D /B /O-D 2^>nul') do set "NewestFile=%%I" & goto CheckTarget
echo ERROR: Found no *.xlsx file in the folder:
echo        "%SourceFolder%"
exit /B 1

:CheckTarget
if not exist "%TargetFolder%\" md "%TargetFolder%\" 2>nul
if exist "%TargetFolder%\" goto GetDateTime
echo ERROR: Failed to access or create the folder:
echo        "%TargetFolder%"
exit /B 2

:GetDateTime
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "DateTime=%%I"
set "BaseName=InventoryReport%DateTime:~0,4%-%DateTime:~4,2%-%DateTime:~6,2% V1"

set "FileNumber=-1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims=." %%I in ('dir "!TargetFolder!\!BaseName!.*.xlsx" /A-D /B 2^>nul ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /I /R /X /C:"!BaseName!\.[0123456789][0123456789]*\.xlsx"') do if %%I GTR !FileNumber! set "FileNumber=%%I"
endlocal & set "FileNumber=%FileNumber%"

set /A FileNumber+=1
copy /B /V "%SourceFolder%\%NewestFile%" "%TargetFolder%\%BaseName%.%FileNumber%.xlsx" >nul ||  exit /B 3
endlocal
```

The first **FOR** loop runs in background one more command process with `%ComSpec% /c` and the command line between the round brackets appended as additional arguments. So executed is with Windows installed to `C:\Windows` in background:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c dir "C:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\53bba593f5d69be\public\uploads\*.xlsx" /A-D /B /O-D 2>nul
```

The background command process executes internal command **DIR** which

- searches in the specified directory
- just for file names because of option `/A-D` (attribute not directory)
- matching the wildcard pattern `*.xlsx` and
- outputs them in bare format with just file name + extension because of option `/B`
- ordered reverse by last modification date because of option `/O-D` which means the file name of newest file is output first and the file name of the oldest file is output last.

It is possible that either the source directory does not exist at all or the source directory does not contain any file matching these criteria. **DIR** would output in this case an error message to handle **STDERR** of background command process which would be redirected by the command process processing the batch file to own handle **STDERR** and so displayed most likely in console window. This error message is not wanted as there is a better one output below the **FOR** loop if there is not found any file for copying. For that reason the error message is redirected already by background command process to device **NUL** to suppress it.

Read the Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10)) for an explanation of `2>nul`. The redirection operator `>` must be escaped with caret character `^` on **FOR** command line to be interpreted as literal character when Windows command interpreter processes this command line before executing command **FOR** which executes the embedded `dir` command line with using a separate command process started in background.

**FOR** captures everything written to handle **STDOUT** of background command process and processes this captured output line by line after the executed background `cmd.exe` terminated itself.

**FOR** with option `/F` ignores always empty lines which do not occur in this case. Every other line would be first split up into substrings using normal space and horizontal tab character as delimiters. The line would be ignored if the first space/tab delimited string starts with default end of line character `;` (semicolon). Otherwise just the first space/tab delimited string would be assigned to loop variable `I` and the command respectively command block would be executed next.

A *.xlsx file name can contain one or more spaces. For that reason the **FOR** option `delims=` is used to define an empty list of string delimiters to disable line splitting completely. It is unusual, but nevertheless possible, that a file name starts with a semicolon. Therefore **FOR** option `eol=|` is also used to define the vertical bar as end of line character which no file name can contain as described by Microsoft in the documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file). So the result is that every file name output by **DIR** in background command process is assigned one after the other completely to the loop variable `I`.

The file name of the newest file is output first and so its name is assigned to environment variable `NewestFile`. Then the first **FOR** loop is exited with using command **GOTO** to jump to the first line below label `CheckTarget` as processing the other file names would be a waste of time and CPU power.

There is a meaningful error message output on no *.xlsx file found to copy and batch file processing is exited with exit code 1 to indicate an error condition to parent process starting this batch file.

Next, with having file name of newest file in source folder, an existence check of target folder is done with creating the target folder if not already existing. A meaningful error message is output if the target folder is still not existing because of other computer or storage device is not running or is not reachable at all or the creation of the target folder failed for whatever reason.

The next two command lines get the current date/time in a region independent format and define the base file name for target file using the current date. For a full description of these two lines see my answer on [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564).

Then the file number is defined with value `-1` and [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled as required for the number comparison done by the next **FOR** loop.

The third **FOR** loop is similar to first **FOR** loop. There is additionally the output of command **DIR** redirected to handle **STDIN** of **FINDSTR** to be filtered for verification if the file name of found file contains really just one or more digits between the dot after `V1` and the dot of the file extension, i.e. this part of the file name is a valid number. It can be assumed that **FINDSTR** outputs the same lines as output by **DIR** on target folder not used for something different than the Excel files with the defined pattern for the file name. The two dots in name of each file must be escaped with a backslash in case-insensitive interpreted regular expression search string on which the space character is interpreted as literal character because of using `/C:` and `/R` and not as OR expression as on omitting `/C:`. For 100% safety on processing later only correct file names `/X` is additionally used to output only file names on which entire file name is matched by the search expression.

This time the **FOR** loop should not assign the entire file name to loop variable `I`. There is of interest only the string between the first dot after `V1` and the file extension `.xlsx`. For that reason the **FOR** option `delims=.` is used to split the file names on dots and option `tokens=2` is used to instruct command **FOR** to assign the second dot delimited string to loop variable `I` which is the incremented file number.

A simple integer comparison is done to determine if the file number of current file name is greater than file number assigned currently to environment variable `FileNumber` in which case this greater file number is assigned to the environment variable `FileNumber`.

The local environment with enabled delayed expansion is no longer needed after knowing the greatest file number of the existing files if there is one at all. So this environment is destroyed which would mean the environment variable `FileNumber` would have again the number `-1` as assigned to the environment variable in initial environment. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38676582/3074564) for details about the commands **SETLOCAL** and **ENDLOCAL**. So to pass the current value of `FileNumber` in current environment to `FileNumber` in previous environment the command line with `endlocal` contains additionally the command `set "FileNumber=%FileNumber%"` which is processed by `cmd.exe`, for example, to `set "FileNumber=12"` before executing the command **ENDLOCAL**. That simple trick is used to pass the greatest file number value to `FileNumber` in previous environment.

See also:

- [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)

The greatest file number of an existing file or `-1` is incremented by one before copying the newest file in source folder with this number and current date in file name to the target folder with verification that the file data were really correct written on target storage media.

The batch file is exited with exit code `3` in case of file copying failed for whatever reason.

Finally the batch file processing ends with explicitly restoring initial execution environment. The last command **ENDLOCAL** would be not really necessary because of Windows command processor runs it implicit on exiting processing of this batch file as done for example on execution of one of the three commands `exit /B`.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `dir /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `findstr /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`

PS: The greatest possible file number is `2147483647`. But a day has only 86400 seconds and more than 65535 files in one directory would be a real problem, too. So the maximum file number `2147483647` should be never reached if no user renames a file in target folder to exceed that maximum number.