# How to copy an entire folder with current date/time in destination folder name?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I tried a lot of searching and working around, but I am unable to get around this sticky problem and hence requesting for help. Almost all the solutions talk about file rename, but I am looking for a folder copy and rename. (I am not a batch or cmd expert.)

I have a requirement as below where I have two directories:

**Source:** `C:\temp\LR_Results\`
**Destination:** `C:\temp\HTML_Reports\`

I have a folder with name `HTML_Report` inside source directory `C:\temp\LR_Results\` which I want to copy to destination directory `C:\temp\HTML_Reports\`.

The requirement is that a timestamp should be added to the folder name `HTML_Report` on being copied to the destination `C:\temp\HTML_Reports\` from the source `C:\temp\LR_Results\`.

So the resulting directory structure should look like:

```
C:\temp\HTML_Reports\HTML_Report_dd_mm_yyyy_hhmmss
```

The timestamp should be the current date/time.

How can this be done with a batch file?

Comment: `move`, `copy` and `ren` work with both files and folders, so I can't imagine, what your problem is. Can you please show your not-yet-working code and explain what exactly doesn't work as intended?

Comment: Unable to add that code in the edit :( getting error. Actually I did try move copy and ren command seperately but was not sure how to add time stamp to it and how to get all of them in a bat file.Now that @Mofi has profided the links I will try to integrate the timestamp code and see how it goes from there

Comment: Thanks @Mofi for the links and Stephan for those simple tricks, I was actually working on a complicated code to do all in one. Now I have a seperate bat file to copy the folder and another one to rename the folder with timestamp using the code from the link shared by Mofi

Answer (score 1):

The following code can be used to get current date and time in format `dd_MM_yyyy_hhmmss` without depending on which country is configured for the account used to run the batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "CurrentDateTime=%%K_%%J_%%I_%%L%%M%%N" & goto CopyDirectory
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "CurrentDateTime=%%I"
set "CurrentDateTime=%CurrentDateTime:~6,2%_%CurrentDateTime:~4,2%_%CurrentDateTime:~0,4%_%CurrentDateTime:~8,6%"

:CopyDirectory
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\temp\LR_Results\HTML_Report" "C:\temp\HTML_Reports\HTML_Report_%CurrentDateTime%\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
endlocal
```

The code uses **ROBOCOPY** to get current date time region independent on being available which is the case by default for Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003 and all later Windows versions. The much slower solution with **WMIC** is used on Windows XP on which **ROBOCOPY** is not available by default.

For a detailed explanation of the three command lines used to get the current date and time region independent with either **ROBOCOPY** or **WMIC** read my answer on [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564).

See also my answer on [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&` which is used to run command **GOTO** immediately after definition of environment variable `CurrentDateTime` as a result of processing the first line output by **ROBOCOPY** with date and time resulting in exiting the loop before processing the next line.

It would be much better to use as date/time format `yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss` which is the international date format. It has the big advantage that multiple subdirectories in `C:\temp\HTML_Reports` with name `HTML_Reports_yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss` displayed sorted alphabetically by name are at the same time also displayed sorted in chronological order. That really helps to get a better overview on the directories with the HTML reports.

The code necessary for date/time format `yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss` with not writing as much as possible on a single command line for most efficient execution:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe (
    for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do (
        %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\temp\LR_Results\HTML_Report" "C:\temp\HTML_Reports\HTML_Report_%%I-%%J-%%K_%%L%%M%%N" /E /R:3 /W:2 /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS
        goto EndBatch
    )
)

for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "CurrentDateTime=%%I"
set "CurrentDateTime=%CurrentDateTime:~0,4%-%CurrentDateTime:~4,2%-%CurrentDateTime:~6,2%_%CurrentDateTime:~8,6%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\temp\LR_Results\HTML_Report" "C:\temp\HTML_Reports\HTML_Report_%CurrentDateTime%\" /C /E /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul

:EndBatch
endlocal
```

This batch file uses **ROBOCOPY** to get region independent the current date and time and to copy the directory on being available. Otherwise **WMIC** is used to get region independent the current date and time and **XCOPY** is used to copy the directory.

The entire task can be done with a batch file containing just one command line on no compatibility with Windows XP must be taken into account and assuming that the required command extensions are enabled and not required delayed environment variable expansion is disabled as by default:

```
@for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do @%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "C:\temp\LR_Results\HTML_Report" "C:\temp\HTML_Reports\HTML_Report_%%I-%%J-%%K_%%L%%M%%N" /E /R:3 /W:2 /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS & exit /B
```

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Answer (score 0):

I am sharing date formatting mechanism below. This will definitely help you create your solution.

```
set foldername=folder1
echo %foldername%_%date:~-4,4%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-10,2%%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
```

For further reading on Batch Scripting Refer its documentation or any tutorial such as [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

So the solution that worked for me is as below.

Yes, it only has `rename` command with the current date time stamp. to copy the folder, I used the inbuild commandline interface solution that comes with Team City Server, and then I made a call to the rename.bat file which did the trick for me.

Below is the rename Code:

```
@echo off
For /f "tokens=2-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('date /t') do (set mydate=%%c-%%a-%%b)
For /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/:" %%a in ("%TIME%") do (set mytime=%%a%%b)
CD C:\temp\HTML_Results
Rename HTML_Report HTML_Report_%mydate%_%mytime%
```

Definitely not the most efficient but works for me.

Comment: you should `Rename "HTML_Report" "HTML_Report_%mydate%_%mytime%"`. `%time%` will have a space before 10 am, which leads to a syntax error without the quotes. (Also I hope your `%time%` is in 24h format. 12h format (with AM/PM) may lead to unintended results.

Comment: On my computer `date /t` gives me `21.06.2020`. That's a good reason to use a [language independent method to get a date/time string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727114/batch-command-date-and-time-in-file-name/18024049#18024049)