# Jenkins job is failing with for loop in command

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, batch-processing, jenkins-cli

In Jenkins, I have few Commands that I am trying to implement in the BAT File.  So I have 2 BAT Files (RUN.BAT & CHANGE.BAT).  In RUN.BAT, Commands are as follows:

```
CD\
E:
CD E:\RESULTS\1
mkdir 1
xcopy E:\I1\0 E:\RESULTS\1
```

Above Given Command would Go to the particular folder and Make a folder named as "1" & then the XCOPY line would copy the contents from folder "O" to folder "1".

Now lets come to CHANGE.BAT here the commands are:

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=-:. " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do ren E:\RESULTS\1 %%a%%b%%c_%%d%%e%%f%%g
```

This command would change the folder name to the Date & Time of the current System.

Here is the issue, the above-given bat files runs completely fine when I call them on my CMD.  But the same doesn't work on the JENKINS & throws me "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

What I am not able to understand is, .bat file works in CMD but the same doesn't work in Jenkins.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: Do you mean that _Jenkins_ is generating that error (and. presumably, not launching the batch file), or that something in the batch file is producing the error? If the latter, which one? `RUN.BAT` or `CHANGE.BAT`. If you don't know whether either is being called, add lines like `echo Start of RUN > "%TEMP%\RUN.LOG"` to each batch file (changing `RUN` to `CHANGE` for the second). If/once you _know_ the batch files are being called add extra lines like `echo Got to XXX >> "%TEMP%\RUN.LOG"` to see where things are failing (not the _two_ `>>` in this version).

Comment: Also, in passing, the first three lines of the first file can probably be replaced by `CD /D E:\RESULTS` (see `CD/?`). And do you mean to create a `1` directory _inside_ the (presumably already existing) `1` directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two batch files `RUN.BAT` and `CHANGE.BAT` can be replaced by a single batch file with just one command line:

```
@for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do @%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "E:\I1\0" "E:\RESULTS\%%I-%%J-%%K_%%L%%M%%N" /E /R:3 /W:2 /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS & exit /B
```

**ROBOCOPY** is the replacement for **XCOPY** and is available by default since Windows Vista and Windows Server 2003.

There is first executed **ROBOCOPY** with an invalid source directory path to get output an error message by **ROBOCOPY** which contains current date and time in a region independent format. Region independent format means that the format of date and time does not depend on which country is configured for the used account which is for Jenkins running as service the built-in local system account. That is most likely the reason for the error message output by command **REN**. The new folder name is different on execution of the batch file with settings for system account in comparison to execution of the batch file with your user account.

Then **ROBOCOPY** is run once again with correct source directory path and the destination directory path with `yyyy-MM-dd_hhmmss` as directory name in `E:\RESULTS`.

**ROBOCOPY** creates automatically like **XCOPY** the entire directory tree to destination directory if the destination directory does not already exist.

The command `exit /B` is required to end the batch file execution after copying the files because of **ROBOCOPY** outputs a second line on error which would be otherwise processed also by **FOR**. It is possible to replace `exit /B` by `goto Label` and the next line is `:Label` if there are more lines to execute like:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1-6 delims=/: " %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do %SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "E:\I1\0" "E:\RESULTS\%%I-%%J-%%K_%%L%%M%%N" /E /R:3 /W:2 /NDL /NFL /NJH /NJS & goto FilesCopied
:FilesCopied
rem More command lines to execute.
endlocal
```

For completeness a solution working also on Windows XP and all later Windows versions:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=2 delims==." %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe OS GET LocalDateTime /VALUE') do set "CurrentDateTime=%%I"
set "CurrentDateTime=%CurrentDateTime:~0,4%-%CurrentDateTime:~4,2%-%CurrentDateTime:~6,2%_%CurrentDateTime:~8,6%"
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "E:\I1\0" "E:\RESULTS\%CurrentDateTime%\" /I /R /Q /Y >nul
endlocal
```

For a full explanation what is output by **ROBOCOPY** on running it first with an invalid source directory path and how **FOR** processes this output see [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564). The Windows XP solution with **WMIC** is explained in detail in the same answer.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `exit /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `wmic /?`
- `wmic os /?`
- `wmic os get /?`
- `wmic os get localdatetime /?`
- `xcopy /?`

Comment: Thank you so much @Mofi this solution helped and It successfully renames the folder as well as copy the contents of the file from one place to another.