# How to compress folder into an archive file by command line without knowing the full name of the folder?

Tags: batch-file, command-line, rar, winrar

I have to compress some folders every month that always start with the number of the referenced month followed by a `-`.

For example:

April: folder is `04- ??????`
May: folder is `05- ???????`

I just know the first part of the folder name. The rest of the folder name is always different.

I´m stuck here:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=" %%G In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).ToString('yyyy')}"') do set "ano=%%G" 

for /f "delims=" %%A In ('PowerShell -Command "&{((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).ToString('MM-')}"') do set "mes=%%A" 

set "winrar=C:\Program Files\winrar"
"%winrar%\rar.exe" a -ibck -ep1  "C:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\%ano%\????????.rar"
```

I just have the information about the first name part of the folder like `04-`.

How can I specify `Rar.exe` to compress the folder by only the first folder name?

Comment: I'm going to assume that `04-` is directly related to `%mes%`, so clearly if your supplied directory uses `%ano%` it is not going to work with the string `04-` which uses a completely different format. Please try a little harder to explain the relationship between the code and the question body.

Comment: the `%ano%` is only to get the correct folder year. `%mes%` is only what i know the first name of the folder i want to compact. A program generate a folder named `%mes%+ uknown name`. So when turn the month, i want compact this previous folder. I have to do it every month. So creating a script to do that will facilitate my job.

Comment: `FOR /D %%G IN ("C:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\%ano%\%mes%*") do set "folder=%%G"`

Comment: Surely it would be more efficient to get the directory name within a single instance of powershell.exe. e.g. `For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NoProfile "$d = ((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).ToString(\"yyyy\\MM-\")+\"*\"; (Get-Item \"C:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\$d\").FullName"') Do @Echo %%G`

Comment: Thank you a lot guys! You really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to read the answers on [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60124351/) for understanding the first **FOR** command line of the batch code below to get current year and month without using PowerShell:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "Year=%%I" & set "Month=%%J" & goto CheckFolder
:CheckFolder
for /D %%I in (%Month%-*) do goto CompressFolders
echo INFO: There is no non-hidden folder with name: %Month%-*
goto EndBatch
:CompressFolders
set "ArchiveFolder=C:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\%Year%"
md "%ArchiveFolder%" 2>nul
if not exist "%ArchiveFolder%\" echo ERROR: Failed to create folder: "%ArchiveFolder%"& goto EndBatch
"C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -idq -m5 -r -y "%ArchiveFolder%\%Month%.rar" "%Month%-*\*"
:EndBatch
popd
endlocal
```

That batch file compresses all folders in directory of the batch file with name starting with current month and a hyphen into a RAR archive file with current month as archive file name. So if the batch file directory contains, for example, the folders `05-Folder` and `05-OtherFolder`, the RAR archive file `05.rar` contains these two folders with all its files and subfolders.

It is of course also possible to compress each folder with name starting with current month and a hyphen into a separate RAR archive file by using the following code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
pushd "%~dp0"
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "Year=%%I" & set "Month=%%J" & goto CheckFolder
:CheckFolder
for /D %%I in (%Month%-*) do goto CompressFolders
echo INFO: There is no non-hidden folder with name: %Month%-*
goto EndBatch
:CompressFolders
set "ArchiveFolder=C:\FOLDER 1\FOLDER 2\FOLDER 3\%Year%"
md "%ArchiveFolder%" 2>nul
if not exist "%ArchiveFolder%\" echo ERROR: Failed to create folder: "%ArchiveFolder%"& goto EndBatch
for /D %%I in (%Month%-*) do "C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -cfg- -ep1 -idq -m5 -r -y "%ArchiveFolder%\%%I.rar" "%%I\"
:EndBatch
popd
endlocal
```

That batch file creates the RAR archive files `05-Folder.rar` and `05-OtherFolder.rar` with the folder names `05-Folder` and `05-OtherFolder` **not** included in the appropriate RAR archive file because of the backslash in `"%%I\"`. The folder names `05-Folder` and `05-OtherFolder` would be included in the archive files on using just `"%%I"`.

Please double click on file `C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.txt` to open this text file and read it from top to bottom. It is the manual of console version `Rar.exe`. The switch `-ibck` is not in this manual because that is an option of the GUI version `WinRAR.exe` to run in background which means minimized to system tray. The `Rar.exe` command line switch `-idq` is used instead to create the archive files in quiet mode showing only errors.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `md /?`
- `popd /?`
- `pushd /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also [single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of operator `&` used multiple times in the two batch files above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your always detailed explanations and efficient codes