# How to get a text file name in located in current directory to a variable with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, file-rename

I have a `.txt` file of which name is used as a reference with the format `AS2204-1` according to the naming scheme `ASyymm-sn` with `yy` being the current year without century, `mm` being the current month and `sn` being a serial number with the current month. I try to get the current file name and increment the serial number by 1 on year and month unchanged, copy the new file name to the clipboard and then rename the text file.

This is my code so far:

```
@echo off
set yy=%date:~12,2%
set mm=%date:~4,2%
set /a sn=0

for %%a in ('dir *.txt') do (set filename=%%a)
set Fmm=%filename:~5,2%
if %Fmm%==%mm% (set /a sn=sn+1) else (set /a sn=1)
echo AS%yy%%mm%^-%sn% |clip 
ren "%filename%.txt"  "AS%yy%%mm%^-%sn%.txt"
```

I can't get the file name assigned to the variable `filename`.

What is wrong with my code and what would be a correct **FOR** loop?

Comment: Your `for` syntax is off. See `for /?`. To evaluate a command, you need the `/f` switch. `"delims="` would be safer and the `dir` command needs the `/b` switch to output only the name and the `/a-d` switch to exclude folder names. Also see [npocmaca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19799236/2152082) for a list of safe methods to get a reliable and portable date/time string.

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer! the reason my syntax is wrong is because i have no idea what im doing. can you pleas write the correct way of the for loop?

Comment: `cd /d "H:\ere is\the folder\containing the text file\"` and `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.txt') do ...`

Comment: `Fmm` is `set` incorrectly. It should be `4,2` as batch defines the first character as character 0. You are defining `sn` as zero, then if the last `.txt` file find in the directory matches the current month, adding `1` to `sn` and if not, you are setting `sn` to 1. So `sn` will always acquire the same number - `1`. You don't say whether `sn` should be 1 or 2-digits, but you probably need to set `sn` to whatever follows `-`, then add 1 - and if no filenames match for the month, start at `1`. Oh, my! such possibilities. Easier to write **that** part as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal
pushd "?:\whichever\directory\contains your\target files"
set "yy=%date:~12,2%"
set "mm=%date:~4,2%"

set "filename="    
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /od AS%yy%%mm%-*.txt 2^>nul') do (set "filename=%%~na")
rem use this line if you use suppressed leading zero
if defined filename (set /a "sn=%filename:*-=%+1") else (set /a sn=1)
rem use this line if you use 2-digit
if defined filename (set /a "sn=1%filename:~-2%+1") else (set /a sn=101)

IF %sn% gtr 100 SET "sn=%sn:~-2%"

echo AS%yy%%mm%-%sn%
ren "whatever.txt"  "AS%yy%%mm%-%sn%.txt"
POPD
goto :eof
```

The `setlocal` ensures that the environment changes (new variables) are removed when the batch terminates.

`pushd` switches to the specified directory. I've no idea what your directory is.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty; in which case `var` becomes *undefined*) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned.

The `for /f` assigns each line of the `dir` "report" to `%%a` in turn. In consequence, `filename` will be set  to the name part only (`%%~na`) of the filename found. `dir /b` produces a list of files to be processed, in basic form (filename only). `/a-d` excludes directorynames, `/od` produces the list in date order. The filemask `AS%yy%%mm%-*.txt` asks for all `.txt` files which match `AS`+thecurrentyearnumber+thecurrentmonthnumber+`-`, so it's not necessary to check the year/month part. The `2^>nul` suppresses error messages should no filename matching the mask be found.

If a filename was found, `filename` will be defined. That's why it's set to *nothing* (which **un**defines it) before the `for` loop.

The filenames must be produced in date order because `ASyymm-10` will sort *before* `ASyymm-2` in the default name-order list.

Well, I've no idea whether you use 1- or 2-digit serial numbers - the processing is different.

If you use the first `if defined...` then `sn` is set to 1 more than (that part of `filename` that exists when all characters up to the `-` are removed) or `1` if no prior file was found.

If you use the second `if defined...` then `sn` is set to 1 more than (`1`+the last 2 characters of `filename`) or `101` if no prior file was found, so `ASyymm-07` would produce `sn=108`. This is necessary because batch interprets a numeric string beginning `0` as **OCTAL** in calculations.

if the result is >100, then use the last 2 characters of `sn`.

I've just `echo`ed the required string to the screen. Echo to the clipboard if you wish.

Well - the rename. It's unclear what the file to be renamed to the calculated name is, so I've used `whatever`. Possibly it's a file named `ASyymm.txt` - if so, replace `whatever` with `AS%yy%%mm%`.

The popd returns to the original directory.

Documentation can be obtained by executing `commandname /?` for most commands but it can be a little cryptic at times. Simply search SO for examples.

Answer (score 0):

There could be used the following batch file for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "YearMonth=%%G%%H" & goto SearchFile
:SearchFile
set "SerialNumber=0"
set "FileNameScheme=AS%YearMonth:~2%-"
for %%G in ("%FileNameScheme%*.txt") do for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%H in ("%%~nG") do if %%H GTR !SerialNumber! (set "SerialNumber=%%H" & set "FileName=%%G")
set /A SerialNumber+=1
echo %FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%| %SystemRoot%\System32\clip.exe
if defined FileName (
    ren "%FileName%" "%FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%.txt"
) else (
    rem del /Q "AS????-*.txt" >nul 2>nul
    echo %FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%>"%FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%.txt"
)
endlocal
```

The first two lines define the required execution environment completely which is:

- command echo mode turned off
- command extensions enabled
- delayed variable expansion enabled

Please read the chapter **Usage of ROBOCOPY to get current date/time** in my answer on [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564) for an explanation of the **FOR** command line which uses **ROBOCOPY** to get current year and month independent on which country (region) is configured for the used account which determines the date format of the dynamic variable `DATE`.

The environment variable `SerialNumber` is defined first with default value `0`.

The environment variable `FileNameScheme` is defined with `AS` at beginning, the current year without the century with always two digits, the current month with always two digits and `-` which results today in the string `AS2204-`.

The command **FOR** is used to search in **current directory** (can by any directory) for one or more non-hidden files matching the wildcard pattern `AS2204-*.txt`.

It is unclear how my files can be in the current directory matching the wildcard pattern `AS????-*.txt`. Therefore the code is written to work also with multiple files matching this wildcard pattern in the current directory.

For each file name matching the wildcard pattern with current year and month already included one more **FOR** loop is used to get the string between the hyphen and the file extension which is hopefully always a number in range `0` to `2147483647` without leading zeros.

This number string is compared with the current value of the environment variable `SerialNumber`. Delayed variable expansion must be enabled because of this number comparison. If the number of the current file is greater the current serial number, the greater number is used further as serial number and the name of the current file is assigned to the environment variable `FileName`.

Please note that `GTR` does not work on number in file has a leading zero as in this case the number would be interpreted as an octal instead of a decimal number which means `08` and `09` would be interpreted as invalid octal numbers with using in this case value `0` for the number comparison.

The default value `0` or the greatest number of files matching `AS2204-*.txt` is next incremented by one using an arithmetic expression.

The file name with the incremented serial number is copied without file extension to the clipboard for whatever purpose.

If there was really found a file with current year and month in its name, this file is now renamed to contain the serial number incremented by one. Otherwise a new file is created with the new file name and containing the file name without file extension as data, for example `AS2204-1`.

There is a line commented out with command **REM** which would delete all files matching the wildcard pattern `AS????-*.txt`, except hidden files ignored by command **DEL** by default and read-only files which are not deleted by command **DEL** by default and matching files being currently opened by an application. It is not clear what to do with the other file(s) matching this pattern from former month(s).

The batch file code could be optimized to following command lines if there is either no or always just one file matching the wildcard pattern `AS????-*.txt` in the current directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=/" %%G in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\robocopy.exe "%SystemDrive%\|" . /NJH') do set "YearMonth=%%G%%H" & goto SearchFile
:SearchFile
set "SerialNumber=0"
set "FileNameScheme=AS%YearMonth:~2%-"
for %%G in ("%FileNameScheme%*.txt") do for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %%H in ("%%~nG") do set "SerialNumber=%%H"
set /A SerialNumber+=1
echo %FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%| %SystemRoot%\System32\clip.exe
if exist "AS????-*.txt" (
    ren "AS????-*.txt" "%FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%.txt"
) else (
    echo %FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%>"%FileNameScheme%%SerialNumber%.txt"
)
endlocal
```

Delayed variable expansion is no longer needed which makes the processing of the batch file a very little bit faster. Serial numbers with one or more leading zeros would be still a problem because of command **SET** on evaluation of an arithmetic expression converts the number string also to an integer with interpreting the number as octal number on having the character `0` at beginning of the number string.

To understand the commands used and how they work, open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window, execute there the following commands, and read the displayed help pages for each command, entirely and carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `rem /?`
- `robocopy /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`

See also:

- Microsoft documentation about [Using command redirection operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490982(v=technet.10))
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) for an explanation of the unconditional command operator `&`.

Answer (score 0):

first of all thanks for all the answers!
I did it that way - it works fine until the renaming part that just doesn't work - any idea why?

```
set "yy=%date:~12,2%"
set "mm=%date:~4,2%"

set "filename=\root\*.txt"

for %%A in (%filename%) do (set x=%%~nA)

set Fmm=%x:~4,2%
set sn=%x:7.1%

if %Fmm%==%mm% (set /a sn=sn+1) else (set /a sn=1)


echo AS%yy%%mm%^-%sn% |clip

set newfilename=AS%yy%%mm%-%sn%.txt
set oldfilename=%x%.txt

ren %oldfilename% %newfilename%
```

Comment: `set sn=%x:7.1%` should be `set "sn=%x:~7,1%"` probably.  Note missing `~` and `,` not `.`

Comment: This is actually a new question

Comment: correct, it was a typo :)