# delete files when already in the destination folder

Tags: file, batch-file, goto, robocopy

I have the code below that transfers the xml to the folder according to the year and month, but sometimes the file has already been copied to the destination folder, how can I inform the code to delete the file if it already exists?

```bash
@ECHO off
set v_day_of_week=
set v_day=
set v_month=
set v_year=
set v_path=

set v_pathOri=d:\XmlRec\
set v_sub_path = 
set v_copy_path = D:\xml\

SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
for /f "tokens=1" %%t in ('date/t') do (
    set v_day_of_week=%%t
    if "%%ta" LSS "a" (set toks=1-3) else (set toks=2-4)
)

::DEBUG echo toks=%toks%

for /f "tokens=2-4 delims=(-)" %%a in ('echo:^|date') do (

    ::DEBUG echo first token=%%a

    if "%%a" GEQ "A" (
        for /f "tokens=%toks% delims=.-/ " %%i in ('date/t') do (
            set '%%a'=%%i
            set '%%b'=%%j
            set 'yy'=%%k
        )
    )
)
if %'yy'% LSS 100 set 'yy'=20%'yy'%
set Today=%'yy'%-%'mm'%-%'dd'%
ENDLOCAL & SET day_of_week=%v_day_of_week% & SET v_year=%'yy'%& SET v_month=%'mm'%& SET v_day=%'dd'%

::ECHO Today is Year: %V_Year% Month: [%V_Month%] Day: [%V_Day%]

set datestring=%V_Year%%V_Month%%V_Day%

::echo %datestring%
::echo day of week=%day_of_week%

if %V_Month% == 01 set v_sub_path=01-Janeiro
if %V_Month% == 02 set v_sub_path=02-Fevereiro
if %V_Month% == 03 set v_sub_path=03-Marco
if %V_Month% == 04 set v_sub_path=04-Abril
if %V_Month% == 05 set v_sub_path=05-Maio
if %V_Month% == 06 set v_sub_path=06-Junho
if %V_Month% == 07 set v_sub_path=07-Julho
if %V_Month% == 08 set v_sub_path=08-Agosto
if %V_Month% == 09 set v_sub_path=09-Setembro
if %V_Month% == 10 set v_sub_path=10-Outubro
if %V_Month% == 11 set v_sub_path=11-Novembro
if %V_Month% == 12 set v_sub_path=12-Dezembro

set v_path=%v_pathOri%%V_Year%\%v_sub_path% 

if exist %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% (del %v_pathOri%*.xml)
else (  
    xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% /R  
    xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml D:\xml\ /R
)

:EOF
```

I tried to insert the code below, but even so, when executing the batch, the message appears:

```bash
if exist %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% (del %v_pathOri%*.xml)
else (  
    xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% /R  
    xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml D:\xml\ /R
```

> ```
> 'd:\XmlRec\2024\01-Janeiro' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> 'else' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.
> Overwrite D:\XmlRecebidos\2024\01-Janeiro\31240117550000013036511650115590.xml (Yes/No/All)?
> ```

Comment: You tagged your question with `robocopy` but you are not using it in your code. Are you not seeing an option in the `robocopy` help that satisfies your condition?

Comment: This is not a valid command. `if exist %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% (del %v_pathOri%*.xml)
    else (  `

Comment: ```set v_copy_path = D:\xml\``` is the wrong syntax. It should read as ```Set "v_copy_path=D:\xml\"```, although you shouldn't use a trailing separator on a directory path. You need to replace your invalid labels, `::`, with remarks, `Rem`. And as already implied `Else` is not an independent command. It is a dependent one and as such should be part of the `If` command which currently precedes it.

Comment: Please read [Time is set incorrectly after midnight](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60126994/3074564) and use the code using __ROBOCOPY__ to get the current date in the wanted format. `for /f "…" %%t in ('date/t') do (` is the worst of all methods which exist for getting the current date. `for /f "…" %%t in ("%DATE%") do (` would at least not start a second `cmd.exe` to output the current date in a country/region depending format captured and processed by `cmd.exe` processing the batch file which offers with the __dynamic__ variable `DATE` getting current date too.

Comment: `day_of_week` is not used at all. It is not necessary for that reason to determine the day of week. See also: [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090) and [Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

Comment: `::` is __not__ the beginning of a comment. It is an invalid label. Labels inside a command block beginning with `(` and ending with matching `)` are not possible and result in an __undefined__ execution behavior. There should be used the remark command `rem` for comments in a batch file, especially inside a command block. Note: `rem` is a command and requires therefore a space after these three characters and the line is parsed like all other command lines in the batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed this part:

```batch-file
if exist %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% (del %v_pathOri%*.xml)
if not exist %v_pathOri%*.xml (
      xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% /R    
      xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml D:\xml\ /R    )
```

And I put `/y` at the end of the line and it worked

```batch-file
set v_path=%v_pathOri%%V_Year%\%v_sub_path% 
xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml %v_path% /R /Y
xcopy %v_pathOri%*.xml D:\xml\ /R /Y
```